# Issue Capitalizing accented words with gsed

Tags: bash

I've issue capitalizing words with gsed:

gsed -e "s/\b(.)/\u\1/g"

The string is:

#### adjéèf the poet

The output desidered is:

#### Adjéèf The Poet

But it it becomes:

#### AdjéÈF The Poet

please note: this is the creative name of an artist so that's just the way it is, with the two different accents...

Comment: `echo "adjéèf the poet" | sed -e "s/^\(.\)/\U\1/g" -e "s/ \(.\)/ \U\1/g”`. Does this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
sed -e 's/\([^ ]*\)/\u\1/g'
```

it create *Adjéèf The Poet*

Answer (score 0):

The `\b` boundary matches a position between two characters where one of them is nonalphabetic and the other is alphabetic.

Which characters exactly count as alphabetic depends on the locale, and also somewhat on the text representation.

Naïvely with a C locale and some legacy 8-bit character set, neither é nor è should count as alphabetics.

Properly under Unicode, both of them should.

I'm guessing you have a non-Unicode locale, or perhaps a `sed` version which doesn't respect that locale. Basically, what you get then is random breakage where the underlying Unicode representation (apparently, I'm guessing, decomposed, so that the accented characters are represented as just *e* followed by a joining diacritic) is accidentally exposed by a tool which doesn't support this abstraction.

A number of more or less involved workarounds are possible; but I'd recommend switching to a tool which is more likely to actually support these intricacies of Unicode.

```
perl -CSD -pe 's/\b(.)/\u$1/g'
```

The following simple demo script (try it online: https://ideone.com/VvXaAt) illustrates how the same string can have multiple Unicode representations, but my Perl solution still handles them all (provided, again, that your locale settings etc are properly configured).

```sh
#!/bin/bash

nfc () {
    perl -CSD -e 'print "NFC: adj\x{00e9}\x{00e8}f the poet\n"'
}
nfd () {
  perl -CSD -e 'print "NFD: adje\x{0301}e\x{0300}f the poet\n"'
}
pc () {
  perl -CSD -pe 's/\b(.)/\u$1/g'
}
echo '** Input **'
nfc
nfd
echo '** Output **'
nfc | pc
nfd | pc
```

Sample output:

```
** Input **
NFC: adjéèf the poet
NFD: adjéèf the poet
** Output **
NFC: Adjéèf The Poet
NFD: Adjéèf The Poet
```

I invite you to experiment with replacing the `pc` function with e.g. a `sed` script and observe any differences. Not every `sed` will be broken, but this is simply not an area where you can expect `sed` on different platforms to behave the same.

Perhaps read more about [Unicode equivalence (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence).